# Why does Go interpret byte as Unicode code point when appending to string?

Tags: go, unicode, utf-8

I need to create a string consisting of a single byte corresponding to an integer of at most 255. It is acceptable that the string is not valid Unicode.

Code:

```golang
import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    n := 255

    s := ""
    s += string(byte(n))
    fmt.Printf("Method 1: %x\n", s)

    sb := strings.Builder{}
    sb.WriteByte(byte(n))
    fmt.Printf("Method 2: %x\n", sb.String())
}
```

Output:

```
Method 1: c3bf
Method 2: ff
```

In the first method, Go appends `ÿ` to the string because 255 is the code point for this Unicode character.

In the second method, Go appends the `0xff` (255) byte to the string. This is the desired result, but is there a simpler way to accomplish this without needing to import the `strings` package? Why does Go interpret the byte as a Unicode code point in the first method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first method, you are converting a byte to a string, which interprets that byte as a unicode code point first.

https://go.dev/ref/spec#Conversions

You can always convert a string to bytes, add a byte, and convert it back to a string:

```
str := string(append([]byte(sourceStr), byteValue))
```